# How can I get the name of column which value is minimum from several rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a table `TestTable` in SQL Server like this:

```
=======================================
No |  Name | Q1  |  Q2  |  Q3  |  Q4  |
=======================================
1  |  ABC  | 10  |  15  |  10  |  50  |
2  |  ABC  | 30  |  25  |  12  |  40  |
3  |  ABC  | 05  |  35  |  13  |  30  |
4  |  ABC  | 10  |  10  |  10  |  20  |
5  |  ABC  | 90  |  50  |  15  |  10  |
======================================
```

What is the best way to write the query that yields the following result? For clarification the database is properly **normalized**.

My expected result :

```
================================================
No |  Name | Q1  |  Q2  |  Q3  |  Q4  | Min    |
================================================
1  |  ABC  | 10  |  15  |  10  |  50  |  Q1,Q3 |
2  |  ABC  | 30  |  25  |  12  |  40  |   Q3   |
3  |  ABC  | 05  |  35  |  13  |  30  |   Q1   |
4  |  ABC  | 10  |  10  |  10  |  20  |Q1,Q2,Q3|
5  |  ABC  | 90  |  50  |  15  |  10  |   Q4   |
================================================
```

Comment: How do you get the output Q* data from the input Q* data?

Comment: What exactly is your problem with this? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Do you know how to get the minimum value out of four?

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't look properly normalised to me at all :( Well, I can understand that creating quarters table and joining would be kinda over-normalisation. About the question - use unpivot first.

Comment: Why do you say *"For clarification the database is properly normalized."* when the sample data we have strongly implies it isn't? Are we missing some additional context here that might aid us in understanding your goals?

Comment: @Arvo: Looks normalized to me. Which normal form do you see violated?

Comment: A properly normalised table would have the columns `No, Name, QuarterNo,QuarterValue`, not 1 column for each quarter (assuming `Q` means Quarter). Part of normalising data is ensuring there are no repeat columns, where in your example `Q` is repeated 4 times.

Comment: Getting the minimum, with the columns set up like that is actually far easier as well.

Comment: Also, your data has the value `05`, does this mean you are storing numerical data as a `varchar`? Numerical data types, in SQL Server, don't store preceding 0's. `DECLARE @i int = 00000005; SELECT @i;` returns `5`, not `00000005`. If you have any values higher than `99`, or negatives, then within the data it will throw any ordering out. For example, the statement `'21' > '121'` is true.

Comment: Hi all i have just changed my first table data, and all values of raw for column Q1,Q2,Q3 and Q4 are integer

Comment: And to add to the "normalization" discussion - there is no indication of year so the concept of "quarter" must be based on an assumption.

Comment: SQL server version?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, no there is no need of a year or quarter it's just a column name nothing else, And for normalization, I have just added for information that's it.

Comment: @Larnu: I don't say that I prefer the table with Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, but I don't see any normal form violated. Do you?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Having multiple columns to display different Q's is a violation of nromal form. Just like if you were to have a table with a customer's details, having the columns `telephone1`,`telephone2` and `telephone3` is actually a violation. This not only forces a customer to not be able to have more than 3 telephone  numbers (I agree, unlikely), but also forces every customer to need to supply it. For true NF there would be a seperate table for telephone numbers. I admit, generally the example i gave is acceptable, but, for the scenario here, NF would (likely) be better.

Comment: @Larnu: So which normal form is it that you see violated? I don't know of any fobidding you to have four columns for yearly quarters. A year consists of exactly four quarters never more and never less. Which normal form demands you plit these into rows? I think you are wrong.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner [1st Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Specifically "No repeating groups": [Database Normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms). Quarter is a repeating group.

Comment: @Larnu: I disagree. A first quarter is distinct from a second quarter. The first quarter comes before the second quarter. It contains the months January, February, and March. A second quarter will never contain these months. It is something different from the first quarter by definition. This is not the case with phone1, phone2 (why is one phone1 and one phone2 and not vice versa? can a phone2 exist without a phone1? ...), but would be the case for phone_no, fax_no, both phone numbers, maybe even the same number, but still two different things semantically.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner then our opinions differ, as I clearly feel you are wrong here. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
--SELECT * INTO #t
--FROM (VALUES 
--(1, 'ABC', 10, 15, 10, 50),
--(2, 'ABC', 30, 25, 12, 40),
--(3, 'ABC', 5, 35, 13, 30),
--(4, 'ABC', 10, 10, 10, 20),
--(5, 'ABC', 90, 50, 15, 10)
-- )T(No,Name,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4)

SELECT *, LEFT([Min],LEN([Min])-1) FROM (
    SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN Q1=M THEN 'Q1,' ELSE '' END+
       CASE WHEN Q2=M THEN 'Q2,' ELSE '' END+
       CASE WHEN Q3=M THEN 'Q3,' ELSE '' END+
       CASE WHEN Q4=M THEN 'Q4,' ELSE '' END [Min]
    FROM #t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(X) M FROM (VALUES (Q1),(Q2),(Q3),(Q4)) T(X)) T
) T
```

*Edit* - This can be even shorter with `STUFF`:

```
SELECT No, Name, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4,
    STUFF(CASE WHEN Q1=M THEN ',Q1' ELSE '' END+
          CASE WHEN Q2=M THEN ',Q2' ELSE '' END+
          CASE WHEN Q3=M THEN ',Q3' ELSE '' END+
          CASE WHEN Q4=M THEN ',Q4' ELSE '' END, 1,1, '') [Min]
FROM #t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(X) M FROM (VALUES (Q1),(Q2),(Q3),(Q4)) T(X)) T
```

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` to implement `LEAST()` and then 4 `CASE` statements to build the result.  Simple and straightforward, without unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Just use `STUFF` to get rid of that nasty comma.

Comment: @MatBailie you can ditch an extra set of parens, wont that make it more readable?

Answer (score 1):

This looks a little convoluted, however, one way might be:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleData ([No] int,
                         [Name] varchar(3),
                         Q1 int,
                         Q2 int,
                         Q3 int,
                         Q4 int);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.SampleData ([No],
                            [Name],
                            Q1,
                            Q2,
                            Q3,
                            Q4)
VALUES (1,'ABC',10,15,10,50),
       (2,'ABC',30,25,12,40),
       (3,'ABC',05,35,13,30),
       (4,'ABC',10,10,10,20),
       (5,'ABC',90,50,15,10);
GO

SELECT *
FROM SampleData;
GO
--Normalise the Data:
WITH T AS(
    SELECT I
    FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4)) V(I)),
Norm AS(
    SELECT SD.[No],
           SD.[name],
           T.I AS Q,
           CHOOSE(T.I,SD.Q1,SD.Q2,SD.Q3,SD.Q4) AS Qv,
           MIN(CHOOSE(T.I,SD.Q1,SD.Q2,SD.Q3,SD.Q4)) OVER (PARTITION BY SD.[No]) AS QvMin
    FROM dbo.SampleData SD
         CROSS JOIN T)
SELECT SD.*,
       STUFF((SELECT ',Q' + CONVERT(varchar(1),n.Q)
              FROM Norm n
              WHERE n.Qv = n.QvMin
                AND n.[No] = SD.[No]
              ORDER BY n.Q
              FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS [Min]
FROM dbo.SampleData SD;
GO
DROP TABLE SampleData;
```

I use a CTE to normalise the data first, which can then easily have the `MIN` function used against. Then a subquery with `FOR XML PATH` can concatenate the values where the value and the min have the same value.

This does however, require 2 scans of the table, where as an answer with several `CASE` expressions will only need the 1.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different here for `SQL Server 2017+` where we can make use of `STRING_AGG`

```
CREATE TABLE testtable(
   No   INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,Name VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
  ,Q1   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Q2   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Q3   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Q4   INTEGER  NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO testtable(No,Name,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4) VALUES
 (1,'ABC',10,15,10,50)
,(2,'ABC',30,25,12,40)
,(3,'ABC',5,35,13,30)
,(4,'ABC',10,10,10,20)
,(5,'ABC',90,50,15,10);
```

```
SELECT No, Name, STRING_AGG(Q_Number, ',') as [Min]
FROM
  (
    SELECT No, Name, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY No ORDER BY Q_Value) as Q_Rank, CA.*
    FROM testtable
    CROSS APPLY ( values (Q1, 'Q1'),(Q2, 'Q2'),(Q3, 'Q3'),(Q4, 'Q4')) CA (Q_Value, Q_Number)
   ) minrank
WHERE Q_Rank = 1
GROUP BY No, Name;
```

```
+----+------+----------+
| No | Name |   Min    |
+----+------+----------+
|  1 | ABC  | Q1,Q3    |
|  2 | ABC  | Q3       |
|  3 | ABC  | Q1       |
|  4 | ABC  | Q1,Q2,Q3 |
|  5 | ABC  | Q4       |
+----+------+----------+
```

I think the big idea here, and from all of the other answers, is that the data needs to be more normalized before the final step of Rank/Min/String_Agg. It should take the form `No | Name | Quarter | Value` and this becomes a cakewalk. Normalization for this data can come through `Cross Apply`, `UNPIVOT`, or `UNION` functionality to get to that middle state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` & use `dense_rank()` function to assign ranking for `Q1, Q2, . .` :

The rest would be done by `cte` & `xml path()` clause :

```
with t as (
     select *, dense_rank() over (partition by No, Name order by qval) as seq
     from TestTable t cross apply
          ( values ('Q1', Q1), ('Q2', Q2), ('Q3', Q3), ('Q4', Q4)
          ) tt (qname, qval)
)

select distinct No, Name, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4,
       stuff( (select ',' + t1.qname
               from t t1 
               where t1.no = t.no and t1.name = t.name and t1.seq = 1
               for xml path('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            )  as Min    
from t;
```

Comment: `for xml path('')` ends up concatentating all of the data from multiple rows, and those values have a comma prepended. `STUFF` removes the leading comma from that result. I hate when people give "credit" for this concatenation to the `stuff` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by concatenating the output of 4 case statements: one for each Q column.

For each Q column, if it's less than or equal to each of the others, return its name plus a comma, else return an empty string.

Do this for each Q column, remove the last comma, and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNPIVOT` then simply select the rows that have the `MIN` value and use `STUFF` or `STRING_AGG` to build the comma separated list:

```
WITH UnPvt([No], Qn, ColName) AS
(
    SELECT [No], Qn, #temp AS ColName
    FROM   #temp
    UNPIVOT (Qn FOR #temp In (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)) AS unpvt
)
SELECT t.*,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ColName
              FROM   UnPvt u1
              WHERE  u1.[No] = t.[No]
              AND    u1.Qn = (SELECT MIN(u2.Qn)
                              FROM   UnPvt u2
                              WHERE  u2.[No] = u1.[No]
                              GROUP BY u2.[No]
                             )
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
from   #temp t
```